# Removing padding / whitespace / gap when using border_left and border_right in a Kable table

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tidyverse, kable

I'm trying to remove these gaps in my kable table (latex / pdf / rmarkdown):

[image]

I essentially just want an outside border and a line that separates the two columns. I thought the best way of doing this was with border_left and border_right, but maybe I'm wrong there?

Code:

```
table <- tribble(~col1, ~col2,
        "Data:", "Some text here.",
        "Transformations:", str_c("Other text here."))

table %>%
    kable("latex", booktabs = T, col.names = NULL, align = "ll") %>%
        kable_styling(full_width = T, latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
        column_spec(1, bold = T, border_left = T, border_right = T, width = "2.8cm") %>%
        column_spec(2, border_right = T)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: don't use the booktabs package together with vertical lines.

Comment: ... in fact don't use vertical lines. fullstop.

Comment: I need to use vertical lines in this instance. Mine or your preference as to whether vertical lines are useful in a table is irrelevant.

Comment: then don't use booktabs

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It don't help. Like midrule = NULL too

Comment: @manro the package must be removed from the preamble. Just setting `=NULL` won't do

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried it without ```booktabs``` package. Can we color only "midline" with ```colortbl```?

Comment: @manro Are you looking for `!{\color{green}\vline}`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, something like this. But how to add this into table made by kableextra?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do it. Maybe this solution isn't beatiful, but...

Answer (score 1):

How you can solve this problem?

**Simply make it into console.**

```
library(kableExtra)

library(tidyverse)

table <- tribble(~col1, ~col2,
                 "Data:", "Some text here.",
                 "Transformations:", str_c("Other text here."))

table %>%
    kable("latex",col.names = NULL) %>%
    kable_paper(latex_options = "hold_position")  %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T, border_left = T) %>%
    column_spec(2, border_right = T)
```

After you'll receive this output:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.8cm}|>{}l|}
\hline
Data: & Some text here.\\
\hline                     #remove this line
\textbf{Transformations:} & Other text here.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Copy and paste this into your RMarkdown and... **Bingo:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```r
library(huxtable)
tribble(~col1, ~col2,
         "Data:", "Some text here.",
         "Transformations:", "Other text here."
       )|>    
       as_huxtable(add_colnames = FALSE) |> 
       set_lr_borders() |> 
       set_outer_borders()
```

[image]